# Simple Matrix Equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations, transpose

$$(2\begin{bmatrix}2 &1 \\-1 &3\end{bmatrix} - 5A^{-1})^{T} = (4A^{T})^{-1}$$

I have approached this question by inverting the transpose and inverse operation on the LHS and then distributing the transpose on the RHS on both matrices. But I tried my solution on Matlab and it seems a wrong approach. How shall I solve this equation?

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to solve for the matrix $A$?

Comment: Can you show in detail how you performed the steps?

Comment: If $A^T = B^T$, then $A=B$.  So just discard the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $B:=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$, then solving for the matrix $A$, the equation
$$(2B-5A^{-1})^{T}=(4A^{T})^{-1}$$
we have
\begin{align*}
(2B-5A^{-1})^{T}=(4A^{T})^{-1} &\iff (2B)^{T}-(5A^{-1})^{T}=(4A^{T})^{-1}\\
&\iff (4A^{T})^{-1}+(5A^{-1})^{T}=(2B)^{T}\\
&\iff (4A^{T})^{-1}+5(A^{-1})^{T}=(2B)^{T}\\
&\iff (4A^{T})^{-1}+5(A^{T})^{-1}=(2B)^{T}\\
& \iff \frac{1}{4}(A^{T})^{-1}+5(A^{T})^{-1}=(2B)^{T}\\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{4}+5\right)(A^{T})^{-1}=(2B)^{T}\\
&\iff (A^{T})^{-1}=\frac{4}{21}(2B)^{T},\\
&\iff (A^{-1})^{T}=\left(\frac{4\cdot 2}{21}\right)B^{T}\\
&\iff ((A^{-1})^{T})^{T}=\left(\left(\frac{4\cdot 2}{21}\right)B^{T}\right)^{T}\\
&\iff A^{-1}=\left( \frac{4\cdot 2}{21} \right)B
\end{align*}
then the result is follows.

**Remark:**

- $(\lambda A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}A^{-1}$ with $\lambda\not=0$.
- $(A^{T})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{T}$.
- $(\lambda A)^{T}=(\lambda) A^{T}$
- $(A^{T})^{T}=A$.

with all the hypotheses well-known.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(A^{-1})^T)=(A^{T})^{-1}$ you can easily get to the fact that
$$\frac{21}{4}A^{-1} = 2 \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$
or
$$A^{-1} =  \begin{bmatrix}
16/21 & 8/21 \\
-8/21 & 8/7
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that $(4A^T)^{-1}\ne 4(A^{-1})^T$. It should be $\frac14(A^{-1})^T$

Comment: @Andrei you're right!  I'll fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help